# Stripe Error 400 - Cannot use stripe token more than once

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I keep receiving error code 400 on my stripe dashboard. It seems like im using the same stripe token more than once and this produces an error. Below is my code.

Js:

```
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
    <script>

    var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: 'pk_test_******************',
        image: '/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
        token: function(token) {
          /*$.post("php/charge.php",{stripeToken:token.id},function(data,status){
              console.log("Data: "+ data+"\nStatus: "+status);
          });*/
          alert(token.used);//alerts false
          $.post("php/charge.php",{stripeToken:token.id});
          alert(token.used);// still alerts false
        }
      });

      $('#myButton').on('click', function(e) {
        // Open Checkout with further options
        handler.open({
          name: 'Demo Site',
          description: '2 widgets',
          currency: "cad",
          amount: 2000
        });
        e.preventDefault();
      });

      // Close Checkout on page navigation
      $(window).on('popstate', function() {
        handler.close();
      });
    </script>
```

Php:

```
<?php
  require_once('config.php');

  $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];

  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      'email' => 'test@test.com',
      'card'  => $token
  ));

  //try {
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      "amount" => 1000, // amount in cents, again
      "currency" => "cad",
      "source" => $token,
      "description" => "Example charge")
    );
    //}catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
      // The card has been declined
    //}
?>
```

Can anyone tell my why I cant charge a customer? How am I using a key multiple times?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You do use the token twice.

First, when creating the customer.
Second, when trying to charge the card.

Instead, you can create a customer and and then pass `$customer->id` to Stripe when you create the charge:

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 1000, // amount in cents, again
  "currency" => "cad",
  "customer" => $customer->id,
  "description" => "Example charge")
);
```

Comment: Maybe stripe changed the API since then, but now you have to supply "customer" and not "source" if you want to use the customer id. So the array would be: array('amout' => 1000, 'currency' => 'cad', 'customer' => $customer->id, 'description' => 'example charge')

Comment: Is it compulsory to create customer if we want to use the same card multiple time?

Answer (score 10):

You have to create the customer to charge him multiple times.

1) Add the Credit card token to customer and create customer

2) Use the customer Id to charge users

```
if (isset($_POST['stripeToken'])){

        $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

// Create a Customer
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
  "source" => $token,
  "description" => "Example customer")
);
```

---

```
// Charge the Customer instead of the card
\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 1000, # amount in cents, again
  "currency" => "usd",
  "customer" => $customer->id)
);
    }
```

for more help visit: https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges

Comment: A customer id is required if using a one off charge and then a day anchor for subscription right after.